# live VS. living

Tags: vocabulary

Can you think of any situation where the following could be used interchangeably or *vice versa*?

live

living

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Native speaker from where? US?

Comment: Or, an educated one.

Comment: COULD IT BE? You know, we have this expression in our own language :"My ears knocked" :D

Comment: We had a [live/living] Christmas tree this year.   (incidentally it's *vice versa*)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Khan's answer.

"Living" has a noun meaning; "live" does not.  For example, "You can earn a living as a translator" is valid; "earn a live as a translator" is nonsense.

The sound of the "i" changes between "live" (the adjective) and "live" (the verb).  "Living" sounds like the verb.  "Live" (the adjective) rhymes with "hive", "jive", and "thrive"; "live" (the verb) sounds like the first syllable of "liver", or the middle syllable of "deliver".  "Living" rhymes with "giving" and "shivving", but **not** with "hiving", "jiving", nor "thriving".

Some examples where "live" and "living"'s adjectival meanings are more-or-less interchangeable:

- She gave me a live plant.
- She gave me a living plant.
- Is it alive?
- Is it living?
- on the other hand, "Is it live?" means "Is it happening now?", not "Is it alive?"
- Live or dead
- Alive or dead  (but "dead or alive" is more common)
- Living or dead

Comment: First off, thanks. Nevertheless, which cases?

Comment: I am looking forward to somebody elaborating their explanations in more accurate way, so that I will learn it very well.

Comment: @nima, jasper's answer is pretty straight forward. When they are used as an adjective to mean that something has life, they are interchangeable. When "live" is used as a verb, or to mean "not recorded", or in its other use to mean electrically charged, they are not interchangeable. When "live" as an adjective is used as an object, it is declined as "alive", but is still interchangeable with "living".

Answer (score 3):

Live and living are both used as adjectives and they have the same meaning *i.e.* not dead.

"Live" is usually used for people. We also use "live" figuratively to mean "not recorded" such as a live show, concert, program, etc.

"Living" is usually used for animals and plants.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, that is: *Is there a situation where they could be used interchangeably*.  There are, of course, plenty of cases where they can't be.